# Perforce Full-text Searching

Tags: full-text-search, ms-office, perforce, full-text-indexing, document-management

Quick question as likely I will have more later.

I'm currently investigating document management solutions and was wondering if anyone has been able to set up full-text searching of a Perforce depot? Specifically for Microsoft Office documents (word, excel) however I can see how this would be useful for general text files.

I remember reading something about full-text searching a while ago (on the P4 KB or mailing list) however couldn't find it after a few searches.

If it not possible, a few suggestions on how a solution could be achieved would be helpful, e.g. using Windows Search Services (Sharepoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to (a) create a client that maps the interesting contents of the depot, (b) set up automation to sync that client regularly (e.g., once a second) so that it's always up-to-date, (c) set up software like dig, Copernicus, the Google Desktop Search Engine, or Lucene to index the contents of the materials sync'd by the client, and (d) set up a web server of some sort which serves up the results of the indexing engine to searchers.

It requires stitching together several components, but I built a system like this about 10 years ago over a weekend and it held together just fine for 7+ years until I moved on from that organization.

Comment: This sounds good; I will investigate further. Most likely will use Microsoft Search Server as the indexer as that providers a web-based portal and is **also** accessible via Windows Explorer which is a huge win. (http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about excel / word format but when dealing with text / code files, P4 grep command may be useful for you. Please give it a try:

[P4 Grep blog](http://www.perforce.com/blog/100712/p4-grep) and [P4 Grep Manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/grep.html)

Hope you get a lead from there.

Comment: Thanks for you input. `p4 grep` could be useful if it could be extended to index office documents. Ideally at the end of the day want something that is accessible to everyone, i.e. not just programmers.

Comment: Yeah true ! Please share the solution with us. It will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: absolutely will share the my research/solution once I come up with one.